# Android kernel from scratch using latest stable from kernel.org?

Tags: android, kernel

Specific infos:
Devices: Nexus 7 (2013) & Nexus 4
Both using google_msm as a base (3.4.0)
As the time of writing the latest stable kernel from kernel.org is 3.19.1
It is possible to do minor updates (like 3.4.0 -> 3.4.106)

Is it possible taking the latest stable release from kernel.org as a base instead of directly pulling from google_msm for my devices and build upon it?

Are there some tools like diff/patch to detect the Android/device specific files and stuff them in in the correct folders without looking through each folder seperately? (Or at least prints it out, so i can do it manually)

I'm a kernel modder at best , so my experience is very low with the kernel itself, tough i'm willing to learn to archive this.

Answer (score 0):

So after further digging around i found this: 
http://www.linaro.org/blog/android-blog/androidization-of-linux-kernel/

I tried doing this with the repo below as a base, but failed miserably at git --rebase.

I've cloned https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git/+/android-3.18 and will try building on that, as it is already an "Androidized" kernel. I think i'll just have to put in the chipset specific stuff, defconfigs  and so on.

My only concern is that the chipset specific stuff will refuse to work with this, but i can't know for sure until i've actually tried and failed, so i'll do that.

If anyone can share some knowledge i'll be grateful.